# Is there a way to avoid writing duplicate code in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I would like to insert more balls into the form. However, in order to allow it to bounce I have to code the same algorithm over and over again for different ball. May I know is there any way I can do it without writing it over and over again? The codes I have are as below.

```
int bBA1; //The x axis from the upper left corner
int bBA2; //The y axis from the upper left corner 
int spdBBA1; //The change of x
int spdBBA2; //The change of y

public StartGame()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void StartGame_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Loads the ball on the screen at bottom of the window
    bBA1 = this.ClientSize.Width / 5; //The x axis the ball is loaded at
    bBA2 = this.ClientSize.Height - 10; //The y axis the ball is loaded at
    spdBBA1 = 1; //The speed of the ball of y
    spdBBA2 = 1; //The speed of the ball of x
}

private void StartGame_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //This is the inner paint color of the circle that is 10 by 10
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, bBA1, bBA2, 10, 10);
    //This is the outline paint color of the circle that is 10 by 10
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, bBA1, bBA2, 10, 10); 
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bBA2 = bBA2 + spdBBA2;
    bBA1 = bBA1 + spdBBA1;

    if (bBA2 < 0)
    {
        spdBBA2 = -spdBBA2; //If y is less than 0 then it changes direction
    }
    else if (bBA1 < -5)
    {
        spdBBA1 = -spdBBA1;
    }
    else if (bBA2 + 10 > this.ClientSize.Height)
    {
        // If y + 10, the radius of the circle is greater than the
        // form width then we change direction
        spdBBA2 = -spdBBA2;
    }
    else if (bBA1 + 10 > this.ClientSize.Width)
    {
        spdBBA1 = -spdBBA1;
    }

    this.Invalidate(); 
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you look into Lists and `foreach` loops

Comment: How 'bout create a `Ball` class with `position`, `size` and `speed`. Then create a method `Bounce` that take screen size as parameter, then do the logic inside that method and update `Ball` position. Then at game loop, you just have to call `Bounce` to update position and `Draw` to draw your `Balls`

Comment: Vague title is not going to be useful to future visitors to the site.

Answer (score 14):

Yes you can! This is one of the many cool features of object oriented programming.

Create a `Ball` class. When you start the game create all the balls you need and store them in a list. From there you can use `foreach` loops to modify the properties of each of your `Ball` objects.

```
public class Ball
{
    public int speedX { get; private set; }
    public int speedY { get; private set; }
    public int positionX { get; private set; }
    public int positionY { get; private set; }

    public Ball(int speedX, int speedY, int positionX, int positionY)
    {
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
        this.positionX = positionX;
        this.positionY = positionY;
    }

    public int setSpeedX(int newSpeed)
    {
        this.speedX = newSpeed;
    }

    //Add any other setters you need.
}
```

Now you have a blueprint for any balls you need to create. Then in your game you can do something like this:

```
public class StartGame
{
    public List<Ball> ballList { get; private set; }

    public StartGame()
    {
        this.ballList = new List<Ball>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StartGame_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add any balls you need here.
        ballList.add(new Ball(5, 10, 1, 1));
        ballList.add(new Ball(2, 17, 2, 9));
        ballList.add(new Ball(4, 12, 7, 5));
    }

    private void StartGame_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //This foreach loop will run through all the balls in ballList
        foreach(Ball ball in ballList)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, ball.positionX, ball.positionY, 10, 10);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, ball.positionX, ball.positionY, 10, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

I wasn't 100% sure how your game worked so I made some guesses with the variables but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! Is it possible for you guys to show me the example?

Comment: Yes, I got the idea. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Good luck with your game!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using a [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and the [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) to store them all

Start by creating a `ball` class and, on start-up, create all the balls you want (at least that you need for the time being) and save that to the list, then just use a `foreach` loop to change anything you want with the ball(s).